# bash: Reading first 'n' entries in a file

Tags: bash, performance, file

I have a series of very big single-lined files of space separated values. It looks like

```
0.993194 0.9684194 0.846847658 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.78499 0.54879564 0.9998545 ...
```

I would like to read the first copy the first n elements of each file.

I could convert the spaces into new lines (`cat file.txt | tr ' ' '\n' > file2.txt`) and then read it line by line and save each line in a new file (`head -n $n file2.txt | while read line; do echo $line >> file3.txt;done`) but that would be very slow. (Above code not tested)

**How can I efficiently copy the first n values of a single-lined file?**

Note: I am fine with copying the first n characters even if this correspond to an undefined number of values.

Comment: what about `cut` command?

Comment: `dd if=BigBoy bs=100 count=1` for 100 bytes, or `head -c 100 BigBoy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using `awk` with specifying the number of records you want?

```
awk -v n=5 '{for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $i}' file
0.993194
0.9684194
0.846847658
1.0
1.0
```

(or) to print in the same line using `printf`

```
awk -v n=5 '{for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s ",$i}' file
0.993194 0.9684194 0.846847658 1.0 1.0
```

(or) using `cut` with `POSIX` compliant options, `-d` for setting the de-limiter and `-f 1-5` for fields 1 through 5.

```
cut -d' ' -f 1-5 file
0.993194 0.9684194 0.846847658 1.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a carefully-designed regex in `egrep`, with the `-o` flag to make it only print the output that matches:

```
egrep -e '^([0-9.]+[ ]*){3}' -o file.txt
```

Prints out:

```
0.993194 0.9684194 0.846847658
```

As grep is a pretty well-known and very heavily-optimized tool, this performs pretty well; I just tried it on a 3-megabyte text file and it didn't take significantly longer than it took on a 30-byte text file.